# Interpreting StackExchange API batch requests

Tags: json, stackexchange-api

My intention is to retrieve a list of linked question ids for an input question. For this, the StackExchange API provides the [linked](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/linked-questions) API which takes as argument a list of semi-colon separated question ids.

The total number of questions for which I need to compute the links is about 1 million. However, the StackExchange API allows a maximum quota of only 10,000 requests. Thus, for my case it would have been ideal for me to send 100 batch requests (separated by semi-colons) at a time. Thus, in a single day I would have got access to 100*10,000 = 1 million links.

Unfortunately, for such batch requests the StackExchange API returns a flat JSON response array, and there is no way to tell which links correspond to which input questions. For example, the question with id 14266328 is linked to two questions having ids 5598291 and 1917935. Whereas the question 14266325 is linked to 3270680.

Now, when I sent the following request to the StackExchange server,

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/14266328%3B14266325/linked?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!--KJA8bUDfrh
```

I got the following response back.

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "question_id": 3270680
    },
    {
      "question_id": 5598291
    },
    {
      "question_id": 1917935
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9988
}
```

The problem is: From this response there is no way of telling what are the questions that are linked to 14266328 and what are the ones that are linked to the other one.

I tried the simple approach of sending only one question_id parameter at a time, but my requests are being blocked after 10,000 requests as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to create a network graph of Stack overflow with nodes as questions and edges as hyperlinks between questions.  The API is an easier way to do it but has rate limits and batch requests would unfortunately require you to make more authenticated requests using up the already scarce rate limits. There are *creative* ways to circumvent this limit but you may run the risk of violating Stack overflow T&C.

That said, I would use the [Stack Exchange Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) to generate this network graph myself. You can look at the textual content of the question and extract the hyperlinks. You can then look the hyperlinks from Stack Overflow (since the [/questions/linked](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/linked-questions) end point only gives you hyperlinks within the website) and generate your graph. All this could be easily done in a programming language like Python using the `re` (extract hyperlinks), `networkx/igraph` (generate a graph and export in GraphML format for future use) and `lxml` (iterative parsing of the data dump XML file).

**Edit**

Turns out that the data dump provides such linked structures via the `postlinks` XML file. That effectively means you no longer have to scrape the textual contents of the post to find hyperlinks.

Comment: well, i didn't want to try out the datadumps because i wanted to work with a small sample of the entire stackovverflow data... however it seems that i can only use the postlinks data dump for my case... thanks for the suggestion...

Comment: `however it seems that i can only use the postlinks data dump for my case.`

This is exactly what you should be doing even if you want to work with a small sample. The API requests aren't worth it for your tasks, IMO.

Comment: yes, what i meant was that i don't need the actual posts... i can only use the postlinks data dump...